# IE/Firefox bubble event

Tags: javascript, button, stoppropagation

Most likely this question has been asked many times before, but as far as I could see, the same responses are given and they do not work for me.

The problem is the following: I have a button control that is rendered as a table and inside this table I have a smaller button. The requirement is that clicking the outer button should show one message and clicking on the small inner button should show another message. 
I have the code inside this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DZFEZ/3/

```
$('#mine').click(function (evt) {
    alert("big button click");
});

$('#mine-fav').click(function (evt) {
    alert("small button click");
    var event = evt || window.event; // cross-browser event    
    if (event) {
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This code works ok on Chrome (and I suspect Opera/Safari. did not check as I cannot install those browsers), but on IE9+ and Fireforx it does not. The event is just triggered on the big outer button, no matter if I click on the small one.

Anybody has any clue why?
Thanks, 
Marius.

Comment: It's not a problem with `stopPropagation()`, the browser is registering your click as being on the big button (because technically it is)

Comment: Ok, but then how can I fix this so that it works consistently through all the browsers?

Comment: After some hours of reading the documentation on the internet, I created an ever more basic example in JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem. It appears that IE/Firefox treats buttons and divs differently when clicks are concerned:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vwK3q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
To resolve your problem just replace outer button to div.
```

Because i think that the button in atomic at those browser and there are some difference in browsers implementation.
You should use elements as expected.
[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vwK3q/6)

Comment: Yes, in the end I used this solution because I realized that there is no way I could make the button+div solition work cross-platform.